# Xcode 6 error when building app for release

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am having issues trying to achieve or even build a release build of an app I am working on. Whenever I try to build the app for release I get an error saying:

> No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

I have the cert for this profile on my computer but in the Developer Portal I only have a certificate for development. Is this causing this error to occur? Do I need to have a Distribution cert to be able to build for release? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am a developer(team member) for a company so I do not have direct access to the Apple Developer Portal.

Comment: Is that the first version ? Or you have a version already on appstore ?

Comment: None in the app store but one pending on iTunes Connect

Comment: That means you already uploaded a version of same app right ? In that case you should use that same certificate

Comment: I thought the same thing to but we had to update and change the certificates because they were going to expire. And that may have changed some things as did not work. Also we made the switch from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 if that means anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know provisioning profiles are a pain :) This is what I do to stay organize and develop/distribute my projects:

1. The developer portal (not xcode) contains the most accurate source of profiles.  For example, imagine you created a merchant certificate, turned on apple pay, and then generated a provisioning profile.  Then let's say you decide you no longer want to use apple pay - the act of turning it off actually invalidates the provisioning profile.  You will see a yellow "invalid" warning in the developer portal, but the provisioning profile may still be available in xcode!  Really annoying.  So I would always make sure that your provisioning profile is valid in the developer profile before distributing an app.
2. In the developer portal, always make sure you have two distribution profiles -- one ad hoc to use with testflight, and one to distribute to the apple store.  You should also have one developer profile to build and debug your code.
3. Once you have your profiles set up, go into xcode and refresh the provisioning profiles as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW26.  I.e. go to preferences, accounts, view details..., and click the refresh button on the bottom left hand corner.
4. Now that xcode's provisioning profiles are updated, you need to now code sign with the right profiles.  To do so, go into your project settings, and go into build settings for both the project and the target.  Under debug, select your iOS development certificate.  Under release, select your iOS distribution certificate.  Under provisioning profile, you will want to select your development profile just to build on your device and debug, your ad hoc distribution profile if you want to archive the project and send it via testflight, or your apple store distribution profile if you want to archive the project and submit it to the apple store.

A few things to note, is that when you are creating the provisioning profiles, you need to specify the certificate you are dealing with.  So if you are creating one of the two distribution profiles, you will need to select your iOS distribution certificate.  And when you select ad hoc distribution, will need to select the devices that you want to be able to distribute too.  Testflight will help you register the devices that you want to distribute to, and once registered, you will be able to select those devices to add them to the provisioning profile.  If the certificate you select in xcode was not used to generate the provisioning profile you selected in xcode, then you will probably get the error you mentioned.  Think of the provisioning profile as the link from you as a developer (i.e. your certificate) and/or your devices to your app id (i.e. your project).